# create regex with Xeger or Generex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get a valid regex for password using **Xeger** or **Generex** by this code:

```
import com.mifmif.common.regex.Generex;
import nl.flotsam.xeger.Xeger;

public class main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          String regex = "((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\p{Punct}]).{8,12})";

          Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);           
          Generex generator1 = new Generex(regex);
          System.out.println(generator.generate());
          System.out.println(generator1.random());
        }
}
```

But what I got in the console is 2 very long strings (much more than 12 chars) and with some very strange chars.

Example for such string:

```
?=??JY??p? x??x??f????v????c4\??6??'??y4?Xoq?d??tT??o??tH?r^c??l??v?l$????*n    xF?+?:y??^?"?dD&o#????????p'f???s?lx[j?iW???^??=?????u??x???=??A??a??)KNyu?ֽSUu?c?wA??jrn???qEi????s??e?Ybp?oj???N@d????\iH?V?u
??c?eM?Y9???kF????b?]rco?gB??L?E?J?\(y1????d?wgg?Mc???D?e?c?o?C?j?w???w??kr?a?????y@VxDi???hCz?j??p?t????h??d5f??L??S??i?Y??z&?@w?X??<os)sF?o??]??M??????k?='????R?V?dPH#CWBV)$d?d?_?d`?%??????Y^??IEK??2?=????dK??d)?8Td]d?=UGK?! ????X@J?X&?MX?={nptrcT]kpp?^op|?o{pPpo
```

How can I create a valid string?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks related: https://github.com/mifmif/Generex/issues/32

Comment: That being said: Your code looks valid (i.e. works with simpler patterns), but generating strings for a complex regular expression is a difficult task. Generex/Xeger might simply be overchallenged with that.

Comment: Also, try to use anchors: put the pattern inside `^` and `$`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any other recommended tool?